# Confused about WiX Project template in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio, wix, visual-studio-2017, wix3.10, wix3.11

Every WiX online tutorial - using Visual Studio - I try to follow asks a user to create a WiX Setup project as follows:

```
Right click on your solution folder and select Add > New Project…
Select ‘Windows Installer XML’ > ‘Setup Project’ and give your installer project a name as shown below:
```

[image]

But after installing `Wix Toolset Visual Studio 2017 Extension` from [here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=RobMensching.WixToolsetVisualStudio2017Extension) and following their instructions to install WiX 3.11 RC2 from [here](http://wixtoolset.org/releases/), what I get in my VS2017 Community Edition is the set of Wix templates as shown below. **Question**: Which of the templates shown in image below should I use to create an `MSI` installer for a simple Winform app? Or, is there something I am missing here? If so, how can I remedy that? [Note: You can click on the image to get a larger view of it]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is known issue and they are working on it: https://github.com/wixtoolset/issues/issues/5531.  This is an RC and not RTM.

You should select WiX Toolset\v3\Setup Project